# How to install MS Office 2010 in Virtual Box Windows VM

Tags: virtualbox, wine, microsoft-office

I have installed a virtual machine on my Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) laptop using VirtualBox. I have also installed Windows 7 Professional.

I need to be able to access MS Office 2010 using the virtual machine. How do I do this?

Do I need to install Wine and then download MS Office 2010?

If so, how do I then access MS Office 2010 from VirtualBox? Do I open Wine from VirtualBox and access through Wine?

Yikes! I am SO confused!

Melodee

Comment: What makes you think that you need Wine? Who suggested that? Wine has nothing to do with managing virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply install MS Office inside the virtual machine as if it were a normal, standalone windows system. i.e. if you can access the installation files (either on CD/DVD or in an .iso or .exe) from inside the virtual machine you should be able to install Office like normal.

If you have an MS Office installation disc, you need to tell VirtualBox to acknowledge your CD/DVD Drive through the VirtualBox storage settings for your Win7 install. You may find help with this [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=48332).

You don't need Wine to install MS Office in your Win7 virtual machine, you just need the appropriate Office installation CD or .exe file to be accessible from the virtual machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MS Office 2010 in Windows 7 Professional that you installed in virtualbox just like you would normally in windows if it was running on its own and not in virtualbox.

You do need a MS Office 2010 disk or be able to download it using windows 7 Professional that is running in virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to enable a shared folder between the host and guest operating system.

2)  Put you ms office executable or folder in the shared folder.

3) Go to the shared folder from the guest os (windows7 in this case ).

4) Copy ms office folder to any folder other then the shared one (in you guest os,this happened to me personnaly ms office was not working because it was still in the shared folder and i tried to install it from there  ).

5) Launch your ms office  installation(of course from the guest win7 , you should have no problem after this step.